# Print {{ node.body.value }} in node--content-type.twig missing figure and figcaption tag of image

Tags: nodes

My code in node--content-type.html.twig is the following.

```
{% autoescape false %}
  {{ node.body.value }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

In my node there are images, centered and with a caption, but when I view the node detail, the images are not centered because of missing figure and figcaption tags.

How can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code to corrected it:

```
<p>{{ content|without('body') }}</p> <!--Other fields in Full content mode-->
{{ content.body }} <!--This is body field. Don't forget config show it in Full content mode-->
```

If someone has a better solution please help me! Sorry my English not good.